# Google play is not displaying the rating of my app nor I am able to search by its name

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded my app on market  3 days ago and its has got about 5 to 6 ratings (from my friends) but its not showing the rating on the market and when I try searching it by its name, its not there. Only when I give my name it filters it out.. I am wondering whether I have missed something.. Has this happened to anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Play (formerly known as Android Market) is (like many other big web services including Apples AppStore) shared via different servers in the background to handle the big amount of requests to it from all over the world.

When publishing a new app it takes some time till all server copies get updated. With publishing my own app it took a few minutes till the detail page worked on the desktop web browser, but over an hour till the link could be opened on my phone. Searching for the name in the Google Play app didn't find my app as a result for a few hours.
The Google Publish area needs even longer to show the statistics of the app downloads.

Being able to download and rate the app suggest that everything was published and set up correct.

Your question is now over a week old, so I would guess in the meantime the problem solved itself?

One more thing: 
The ratings of an Android app are counted over all locales. But when you look at the detail page only those text message ratings are shown, that match your locale settings. So it depends on your Account localea on the phone or the webbrowser-Settings (can be changed at the bottom of the detail page). In the Publish area you should see all reports.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing and your answer shined light on my problem. I have several reviews of different locale and was wondering why they never show up.. (they are good ones from good people!) what a pity.. I thought google will translate it for us :)